# Selenium Drag&Drop in testing javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

Need your help in such a specific situation.
I use Selenium framework for testing the application, which based on "*ext js*" library.
There are 2 trees of elements. I need to move an element from one tree to another element in the second tree.
I use `dragAndDropToObject(xpath1,xpath2)`;
I can see that method takes '`xpath1`' element, tries to bring it to the '`xpath2`' element and no result - the element '`xpath1`' comes back to the previous place. It seems like the method doesn't see the pointed object, doesn't release a taken element on that.
If I use another method of Selenium - f.e. `click(xpath2);` - it clicks on the pointed object, so the problem is in `dragAndDropToObject`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to extend selenium by the user-extensions.js file.

Drag & drop selenium tests have been made on the [SweetDEV RIA](http://sweetdev-ria.sourceforge.net/) open source tag library.

You may find [a very interesting method (Selenium.prototype.doDragTo) on the SweetDEV RIA SVN repository](http://sweetdev-ria.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sweetdev-ria/sweetdev-ria/trunk/sweetdev-ria-test/src/test/resources/user-extensions.js?revision=7533&view=markup#l_122).